# How to start process over ssh that doesn't terminate when session ends?

Tags: process, ssh, jobs, schedule

Is there a way to start a process using ssh that doesn't terminate when the ssh session terminates? I want the job to keep running on the computer I'm ssh-ing into without me having to keep the connection open.

Comment: While a good question, this does not really deal with programming. Voting to move to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) (assuming you are SSHing into *nix server)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) utility.

Comment: +1 for screen. I use it start a long running process before I leave work. Then I detach the screen and I can check its progress later by reattaching to the screen session while logged in from home.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to screen is [dtach](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/). dtach is smaller and more lightweight - in fact it is just the detach part of the screen utility.