# running process on remote machine using ssh

Tags: process, ssh

I am running a process that takes long time to finish on a remote server. The process gets killed when my ssh connection to the remote machine is dropped. Is there a way I can continue running the process even after my ssh connection drops?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190100/how-to-start-process-over-ssh-that-doesnt-terminate-when-session-ends).

The answer provided there was to use the POSIX command *nohup* to ignore the ssh termination and allow the process to continue running.